# Elasticsearch 5.5.2 -- Data transformation upon inserting

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting

I am using the ES 5.5.2. I would like to transform the document before inserting into the index. I have found the solution that I have to add the following section into my document mapping:

```
    "transform": {
      "script": "here_goes_the_processing_logic",
      "lang": "groovy"
    }
```

But, when I tried to do this I got the following error:

```
      "error": {
        "root_cause": [
          {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [transform : {the script body}
        ]
}
```

Does the ES 5.5.2 support such mechanism? If no, then how can I accomplish this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're trying to use [mapping transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/mapping-transform.html#mapping-transform), but it was deprecated in 2.0.0 and removed after 5.0. To accomplish something like this in ES 5, you can use an [ingest node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/ingest.html) and add your transformation as a [script processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/script-processor.html) in the [pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/pipeline.html).